# How do I give input to a merged model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have created a model by merging five small models where each four of them take an array with four-element and the last one takes one.
My input array contains 626 lists of

```
[np.ones(4),np.ones(4), np.ones(4),np.ones(4),np.ones(1)]
```

How do I give this as input while fitting the model?
How does batching work here?
[image: Merged model]

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2, input3], outputs=outputs)
```

Comment: Hi I think you misunderstood my question. I have completed merging the models. However, I am confused about how to give input while fitting the model. I have edited the question as you can see.